# Quartz 2.x Trigger

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

I need a cron trigger to fire daily starting at 22:00 every minute until 23:00.  Could someone please give me the cron expression for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the official doc at http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger :

> 0 * 14 * * ?  Fire every minute starting at 2pm and ending at 2:59pm,
>   every day